# how to make a button do multiple things?

Tags: android

I have a question regarding android development. I am trying to make an app that changes the screen color from red to blue and then green. I have asigned an onClickListener to a relativeLayout, that turns the screen from white to red. How do I make that same onClickListener do multiple things in an order, so that when I click the screen once it turns it to red and when I click it again it will turn the screen to blue etc.

Here is my code so far:

```
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this, one way is by maintaining state; once clicked set the state to that color, then when clicked again check the state and react accordingly. So for example, state can be an `enum` - Red, Blue, Green. Upon initial click, set to Red. If clicked again, check state and set to appropriate color, so on...

Answer (score 2):

Store the list of desired colors in an array.  Keep track of the current color index and increment after each click like so:

```
final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    String[] colors = new String[]{"#ff0000", "#00ff00", "#0000ff"};
    int colorIndex = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String color = colors[colorIndex];
        colorIndex = colorIndex++ % colors.length;
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
});
```

The modulo operator (%) ensures we don't index past the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

track the state of your click. Like this

```
private int colorState =0;

    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

        layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(colorState){
        case 0:
          layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            break;
        case 1:
          layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            break;
        case 2:
          layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
            break;

        colorState++;
    }
```

Comment: I think it would also be helpful to have `colorState` reset to 0 as a default case. Otherwise this code won't work when it's value goes over 2.

Comment: Yeah its up to how you want to implement. Its just an example :D